# Filter array with multiple conditions returning empty array

Tags: javascript, filter

I am having an issue with my filtering on multiple conditions

my array is..

```
const junkData = [
   { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" },
   { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" },
   { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" },
   { CatalogID: 2, Area: "Area D" },
   { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
   { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
   { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
   { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" }
];
```

My filter is

```
const junkDataFilter = junkData.filter(f=>f.Area === "Area A" && f.CatalogID === -1);
```

What I expecting to see was...

```
junkDataFilter = [
    { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" },
    { CatalogID: 2, Area: "Area A" },
    { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" },
    { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
    { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
    { CatalogID: -1, Area: "" },
    { CatalogID: 1, Area: "Area A" }
];
```

What I keep getting is an empty array

```js
(() => {
  const junkData = [{
      CatalogID: 1,
      Area: "Area A"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 1,
      Area: "Area A"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 1,
      Area: "Area A"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 2,
      Area: "Area D"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: -1,
      Area: ""
    },
    {
      CatalogID: -1,
      Area: ""
    },
    {
      CatalogID: -1,
      Area: ""
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 1,
      Area: "Area A"
    }
  ];

  const junkDataFilter = junkData.filter(f => f.Area === "Area A" && f.CatalogID === -1);

  console.log(junkDataFilter);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is nothing with `Area === "Area A"` **AND** `CatalogID === -1` in your array. All the objects have ``Area === "Area A"`` **OR** `CatalogID === -1`. Except `{ CatalogID: 2, Area: "Area D" }`

Comment: @VLAZ, so its a logic thing, so how do I get it to return the way I need?

Comment: Yes. AND - both have to be true at the same time. OR - at least one has to be true.

Comment: @VLAZ, its been a long day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to || instead of &&

```
const junkDataFilter = junkData.filter(f=>f.Area === "Area A" || f.CatalogID === -1);
```